# OpenCL CPU is faster than OpenCL GPU for naive matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, opencl

I created a simple OpenCL program that multiplies two NxN matrices using naive matrix multiplication (the one with O(n^3) complexity). Each value of each matrices is a single precision 32bit floating point. The program is compiled using visual studio 2015 on Windows 10 x64.

With N=2048 and using intel OpenCL platform, The time elapsed is as follows:

- result CPU (Core i7 3517U) : 16 sec
- result GPU (Intel HD 4000) : 43 sec

EDIT : to clarify, the CPU result above was performed using Intel's OpenCL CPU implementation. On a regular C++ serial CPU implementation, it took 82 seconds.

And with Nvidia OpenCL platform on the same hardware, the result is not much different:

- result GPU (GeForce 720M) : 32 sec

Here is the C++ code that call the OpenCL :

```
//create kernel
cl_kernel krnl = clCreateKernel(program, "matmult", NULL);
//create buffer (for source matrices, read only)
cl_mem srcBuff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*size*size, src, NULL);
cl_mem dstBuff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*size*size, dst, NULL);
//buffer for result
float* res = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*size*size);
cl_mem resBuff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float)*size*size, NULL, NULL);
//set kernel args
clSetKernelArg(krnl, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &srcBuff);
clSetKernelArg(krnl, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &dstBuff);
clSetKernelArg(krnl, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &resBuff);
clSetKernelArg(krnl, 3, sizeof(int), &size);
//run
size_t dimSizes[] = { size,size };
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, krnl, 2, NULL, dimSizes, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, resBuff, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*size*size, res, 0, NULL, NULL);
return res;
```

And here is the OpenCL kernel function:

```
__kernel void matmult(__global const float* src, __global const float* dst, 
                        __global float* ret, const int n) {
    int y=get_global_id(0);
    int x=get_global_id(1);
    float sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum+=src[y*n+i] * dst[i*n+x];
    }
    ret[y*n+x]=sum;
}
```

Comment: But why does that surprises you? OpenCL is not a silver bullet, and it is known that you need to tune a lot your program to your computer. Did you try with other sizes (e.g. N=1024)

Comment: well, I've edited my post to show that the CPU OpenCL is clearly a lot faster than regular C++ implementation. The problem is, the GPU OpenCL performs much slower than the CPU OpenCL. This happens regardless of N size.

Comment: Again, why does that surprise you? Read more about OpenCL; you need to *explicit* and *tune* the parallelism... STFW for "OpenCL matrix product", see e.g. [this](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/home/simonm/workshops/OpenCL_lecture3.pdf). OpenCL is not about *naive* algorithms, but tuned ones.

Comment: Your code is scalar but hardware is vector(SIMD). HD4000 has 128 cores which are grouped as 8 so you should use float8 type when computing so it becomes more efficient when loading/storing too. If its hard, then make it matrix-level parallelism so it can multiply multiple matrices at the same time. Maybe they be sub-matrices of this 2048 x 2048 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make more effort to make it run faster on GPU. Use local memory, tiling, etc.

There is lot of literature about that. For example here is step by step tutorial: [Tutorial: OpenCL SGEMM tuning for Kepler](http://www.cedricnugteren.nl/tutorial.php?page=1).

Comment: The slides also yield similiar results with the naive implementation (the OpenCL CPU is faster than GPU). Seems that I have to really optimize my code. Thank you for the replies.